# Ускорить загрузку файлов через apache httpclient

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient

Мой клиент загружает файлы в хранилище при помощи такой функции:

```
public boolean uploadFile(FileModel file, String remoteFileTempId) {
        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            if (file.getPath() == null) {
                System.out.println("File upload: local file does not exist");
                return false;
            }
            File fileToPost = new File(file.getPath());
            HttpEntity data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                    .addBinaryBody("file", fileToPost, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, file.getName())
                    .build();
            HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder
                    .post(append)
                    .setEntity(data)
                    .addHeader("fileTempId", remoteFileTempId)
                    .build();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Большие файлы (до 40 мб) загружаются достаточно долго. Можно ли ускорить загрузку каким-то образом? Например, отправлять файл более крупными частями.

Comment: А какие оценки по времени? Сколько занимает сейчас? Тест на локальной машине или с удалённой? А почему http, а не ftp или один из наследников последнего?

Comment: @Michel_T, сейчас 37 мб отправляется секунд 15-20. HTTP, потому что у нас рест.

Comment: поставить инет быстрее. но и то не факт. Могут быть проблемы между вами и серваком и это Вы уже никак не исправите.

Comment: Можно еще сжимать файлы, что бы меньше весили.